# Restrict file deletion on a git merge

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, gitlab, git-merge

Good day. I have a project my own GitLab and this is a .NET development project. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with git tools. It has been 6 months of full advantages with this powerful combo. But now new people is integrating on the project. So for different working groups I'm making a bare clones of this project with some files and directories deleted. The first one was for Web Development.

At this point I made a test to merge from the Web project to the big one (That it has class libs and the web project itself). And it did it great. Now one week later, i was ready for the first real merge. And it failed. The big project deleted the files and directories that I erased in the little one.

I don't know, what am i doing wrong?, I'm pretty sure the commands are the same. I write down them in my blocknote. But this behavior is new for me. So I'm looking a way to restrict the deletion in the big one when merge process is executing.

Can anybody help me please?. Thanks in advance

**--==UPDATE==--**:

I've just to realize that my test was from the big one to the little one.

```
git clone WebVista http://versioner.domain.com/omelendez/WebVista.git
git remote add WebMVC http://versioner.domain.com/omelendez/WebMVC.git
git fetch WebMVC
git checkout -b WebMVC WebMVC/master
git checkout master
git merge WebMVC
```

Conflicts are resolved in VS. Thing here is it works perfectly here. No addition of the class libraries, that's because the git ignore, I used it to delete the directories and files. When I did the clone, I ignored the class library projects and ran these commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Web Development Project"
```

The guy forked this project made his changes and made a merge request. That's the good part

I'm still without clue how to merge into the big one. If someone has some idea about it, I'll appreciate if that person can write about it.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I could resolve this. The delete action remains as a trail in the git history, when it was done in a cloned repo. So what i had to do is restore all the files from a previous commit.

after the "bad" merge:

```
git checkout HEAD~1 -- filename.ext
git checkout HEAD~1 -- directory1    <-- (If u need to restore a whole directory)

Later in the VS I made the changes respectively, about adding the projects manually. Then commit and sync.
```

Thanks to cbreak in the #git irc channel for the support. It works very well.